# I am having the error with a Subquery returning more than one value. How do I reduce to one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

At the very end of the Stored procedure a SELECT statement is made to display the contents of the Table including function that will simultaneously populate fields in the table.

Here is the Select Statement:

```
IF @type = 'SH'
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM #History
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
ELSE
SELECT DISTINCT   AmhazName
        ,Activity
        ,ServiceName
        ,Sarid
        ,PerformedDate
        ,UserRole
        ,Details
        ,dbo.ufn_SarHistoryActionText(sarid, status, performeddate) AS [ActionText]
        ,FullName
        ,CategoryDescription
        ,StatusDescription
        ,ActionPerformed

        ,Case 
            when Details like '%ProjManagerId%'
                Then    dbo.ufn_GetUserForHistoryReport (PerformedDate, SarId, '%ProjManagerId%')
        Else
            --when Details like '%UserId%'
                 dbo.ufn_GetUserForHistoryReport (PerformedDate, SarId, '%UserId%') 
                 --(select 'no user') as [AssignedUser]
        End as [AssignedUser]

        --,dbo.ufn_GetPMForHistoryReport(PerformedDate, SarId) as [AssignedUser]
FROM #history
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
DROP TABLE #Historyw
```

Here is the function I believe is causing problems:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_SarHistoryActionText] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
      @sarID int
    , @status varchar(6)
    , @statusDate datetime
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result varchar(100)

    set @Result = (
                    SELECT C.ActionText
                    from LuStatusChange as C
                    WHERE   C.FromStatus = dbo.ufn_SarHistoryPriorStatus(@sarID,@status,@statusDate)
                        AND C.ToStatus = @status
                    )

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

As I debug and walk through loads of values, I haven't come across anything that resulted in multiple values. maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Without access to your data there is not much we can offer. As for your function, it has the potential to return multiple values, but that depends on what the data looks like. You can always add a `TOP 1` and an `ORDER BY` to the select but really you need to find the values which cause the issue. Without access to said values there is nothing we can do.

Comment: Well, it is obvious that the error comes from `ufn_SarHistoryActionText`. When that sub-query returns more than one value you will get that error message. You can find out the possible row by using `select FromStatus, ToStatus from LuStatusChange group by FromStatus, ToStatus having count(*) > 1`

Comment: You have three scalar functions in use - and potentially a fourth depending on that commented out line as the last column. The first step is to stop **believing** and start actually debugging your code to find the actual function that **is** causing the error. You can use "TOP 1" in the query that retrieves the value for assignment - but better to figure out if you have made a false assumption about your schema or if you have a logic flaw in the query. Scalar functions calling scalar functions has a bad smell.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the Help. It worked out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add TOP 1 in the select inside the function:

```
SELECT TOP 1 C.ActionText
```